# Android ActionBar settings

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am making ActionBar where is date and a button. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        String dateString = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy/MM/dd", new java.util.Date());
        actionBar.setTitle(dateString); 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        Button edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        Button discard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discard);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add.class);
                startActivity(intent); 

               break;
        }
        return false;
        }
    }
```

And a problem is that the Date appears in ActionBar but button don't. Why the button don't appear?

Comment: It can be useful if you post your `menu/main.xml` layout. The problem could be in improper configuration of `android:showAsAction` tag

Comment: Thanks... That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines:

```
    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    Button edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    Button discard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discard);
```

to

```
    MenuItem add = menu.findItem(R.id.add);
    MenuItem edit =  menu.findItem(R.id.edit);
    MenuItem discard = menu.findItem(R.id.discard);
```

> main menu XML file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
       android:id="@+id/add"
       android:showAsAction="never"
       android:title="add"/>
    <item
       android:id="@+id/edit"
       android:showAsAction="always"
       android:title="edit"/>
    <item
       android:id="@+id/discard"
       android:showAsAction="always"
       android:title="discard"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

It needs to be in your onCreate method.